# Can Sunnis eat meat authorised halal by Shi'a?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, shiism, food, halal-certification

The city main mosque in a non Muslim country is Shi'a and the halal certification process is controlled by them. Can we eat meat from a restaurant (which is owned and staffed by Sunnis) if the halal certificate on the wall is from a Shi'a governing body?

Comment: AFAIK Shia's are more restricted and therefore cover all Sunni restrictions. I know *some* Sunnis eat Kosher meat and say it's halal. Shia's don't. Though Shias/Sunnies both eat non-meat Kosheri products.

Answer (score 1):

```
           In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

> Can Sunnis eat meat authorised halal by Shi'a?

**Yes.**

Actually Shia Muslims slaughter based on Islamic orders/circumstances; as a result, it can be allowed for both Sunnis/Shias to eat of such circumstances (from Shias).

**Sources:**

- [www.al-islam.org/islamic-laws-ayatullah-ali-al-husayni-al-sistani](https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-laws-ayatullah-ali-al-husayni-al-sistani/slaughtering-and-hunting-animals)
- [www.al-islam.org/a-summary-of-rulings-makarim-shirazi](https://www.al-islam.org/a-summary-of-rulings-makarim-shirazi/rules-slaughtering-and-hunting)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference between Shias or Sunnis in halal and haram.

You can eat the meat of both of them. There is one condition that the meat be

haram if an animal is slaughtered to other than Allah.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE.  Generally, answers are better received when they provide references.  See: [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)